# I can connect oracle 10g through command prompt but i can't connect it oracle 10g home page through Home page?

Tags: database, oracle, connection, oracle10g

I can connect `oracle` through `command prompt` but I can't  connect it  oracle home page through Home page, recently it's showing error, I used always from `localhost`. Suddenly I can't enter through my `Oracle 10g` home page?

```
1.I do TRIED to SET CHROME SETTING
2.PROXY SERVER FROM MY PC ALSO
3.I TRIED TO OPEN IT FROM FIREFOX ALSO , IT ALSO SHOWING ERROR
```

[here the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XlD4.png)

Comment: What changed on your system between "always" and "recently"?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "oracle home page", it looks like you're trying to connect to a local instance of **Oracle Application Express** (maybe 4.2, since you're using Oracle Database 10g).

Probably your **Oracle HTTP Server** Windows service has stopped. There are two ways you could try to fix this:

A) Open Windows Settings, type "services", and open the Services control panel. Scroll down to the names starting with "Oracle", right-click on the HTTP Server one, and click "start".

B) Follow [the instructions in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12255/overview.htm#1008162):

```
cd %ORACLE_HOME%\opmn\bin
opmnctl verbose startproc ias-component=HTTP_Server
```

If you're still having problems, you might have to look at the HTTP server logs - I think for 10g they were stored in `ORACLE_HOME\Apache\Apache\logs\`, but I'm really not sure.